# how to edit listview row with a combo

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a `ListView` with rows on it.  When I click on a particular cell, I want that selected cell to be editable with a combo box and the thing is I have done it, but the combox box still remains even after editing.  I want the combo box to change back to textblock.

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" 
   x:Key="GridEditStyle">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" 
     Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
             AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},
         Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, 
             ConverterParameter=True}" />
        </Style>

 <ComboBox SelectedItem="Present"
                                                           ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, 
                                                            Path=AvailablePublishers}" 
                                                            Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}" />
```

code behind is

```
   private ObservableCollection<string> _AvailablePublishers =
 new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public Student_Attendance()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _AvailablePublishers.Add("Present");
        _AvailablePublishers.Add("Absent");
        _AvailablePublishers.Add("Late");



    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> AvailablePublishers
    { get { return _AvailablePublishers; } }

  public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
      object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool param = bool.Parse(parameter as string);
        bool val = (bool)value;

        return val == param ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
      object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

plz help me out 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know if you used a `DataGrid`, you would't have to do anything for switching the viewing and editing templates, it's done automatically ... here's a sample to get you started:

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ...}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=AvailablePublishers}" SelectedItem="{Binding ...}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: thank u very much. Got a question can datgrid have dynamic multiple columns with dynamic headers and inside the columns a checkbox for each cell? can we know header name of the checkbox checked?

Comment: yeah, if I understand what you imply by dynamic. You can control DataGrid any way you like, as with most controls - it's just a matter of how much time and effort you can and willing to put.

Comment: Also, note, that you can achieve what you were looking for with the ListView, it's just more trouble. I've got a couple of posts here where, I thought I helped someone with that. But when I saw your question, I just thought, why go through all that trouble, when you can just do what you need out of the box? Anyway, glad to be off help. Take it easy

Comment: Sorry, one more note, the only reason now people use ListView over DataGrid is that ListView is a bit more light weight, but for what you're doing - toggling templates, DataGrid is the way to go..

Comment: thank you very much.Any reference to look into for datagrid coz haven't used as such

Comment: sure, just google "WPF DataGrid samples", note, that it came into .NET 3.5 through Toolkit.DataGrid. So it's been around for a long time! There is Telerik DataGrid as well as Telerik.ListView that has cell editing templates also